# Have a message after a User is deleted in Typescript and GraphQL

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm

I'm new to Typescript and GraphQL and I implemented some CRUD rules in a To-Do list.
In general, I don't know how to include messages inside the GraphQl in the situation like I delete a User and I would like to see `deleted: true` in the response.

What I did until now was to create all the logics and I'm able to delete a User.

Delete User mutation:

```
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { Entities } from '../../../entities/entities';

export const deleteUserMutation = {
    async deleteUser(_, { id }): Promise<typeof user> {
        const repository = getRepository(Entities.user);
        const user = await repository.findOne({ id });
        await repository.delete({ id });
        return {
            ...user,
        };
    },
};
```

User Mutation:

```
 export const UserMutation = `
        extend type Mutation {
          createUser (
            user: NewUserPatch!
          ): User
          updateUser (
            id: String!
            patch: UserPatch!
          ): User
          deleteUser (
            id: String!
          ): User
        }
    `;
```

I don't know if I should show more and in case please comment so I will include.

My issue to recap is that I need to see a message in the response saying like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "deleteUser": {
      "deleted": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You may wish to tag this `typeorm` because this question looks specific to that library and not graphql in general. Typically you pass data to queries through a `variables property

Answer (score 0):

To return the desired message of `"deleted": true`, you will need to modify your mutation schema and resolver logic. Currently, the `deleteUser` mutation is implemented to return an on object of type User, which I assume does not include the boolean flag you would like to include. To resolve this, you could create a payload type to be returned from `deleteUser` mutation, which would include the boolean flag, and optionally data regarding the deleted user.

```
    type DeleteUserPayload {
        deleted: Boolean!
        user: User
    }

    // Update mutation with new payload type
    deleteUser (id: String!): DeleteUserPayload
```

It will be up to your implementation in the resolver for `deleteUser` to ensure the appropriate payload values are returned.